# model.predict(img) - error

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

Что упускаю ? не получается передать 1 подготовленное изображение в `model.predict(img)`

Модель на вход ожидает:

`(batchSize,imageWeidth,imageHeidth,imgChannels)`

`(1,150,80,1)`

**Ошибка:**

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 150, 80, 1), found shape=(None, 80, 1)
```

**Код:**

```
# Создать тензор из изображения

# 1. Считать изображение
img = tf.io.read_file('/content/drive/MyDrive/testImg.jpg')
# 2. Декодировать и преобразовать в оттенки серого
img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=1)
# 3. Преобразовать в float32 в диапазоне [0, 1]
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
# 4. Измененить до нужного размера
img = tf.image.resize(img, [80, 150])

print(img.shape)

# 5. Переместить
img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])

print(img.shape)

pred = prediction_model.predict(img)
pred_texts = decode_batch_predictions(pred)
```

**Вывод в консоли:**

```
(80, 150, 1)
(150, 80, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-d7d5c6459088> in <module>
     17 print(img.shape)
     18 
---> 19 pred = prediction_model.predict(img)
     20 #pred_texts = decode_batch_predictions(pred)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__predict_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1845, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1834, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1823, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1791, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 150, 80, 1), found shape=(None, 80, 1)
```

**prediction_model.summary()**

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 image (InputLayer)          [(None, 150, 80, 1)]      0         
                                                                 
 Conv1 (Conv2D)              (None, 150, 80, 32)       320       
                                                                 
 pool1 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 75, 40, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 Conv2 (Conv2D)              (None, 75, 40, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 pool2 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 37, 20, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 37, 1280)          0         
                                                                 
 dense1 (Dense)              (None, 37, 64)            81984     
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 37, 64)            0         
                                                                 
 bidirectional (Bidirectiona  (None, 37, 256)          197632    
 l)                                                              
                                                                 
 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectio  (None, 37, 128)          164352    
 nal)                                                            
                                                                 
 dense2 (Dense)              (None, 37, 12)            1548      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 464,332
Trainable params: 464,332
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Модель наверняка ожидает набор картинок, а не одну картинку. Так что как минимум нужно ещё одну размерность наверное добавить.

Comment: @CrazyElf Набор одних и тех же ? Или разных ?

Comment: Я про то, что `predict` наверняка ждёт грубо говоря массив, а вы ему единичное значение передаёте. Если бы это было питоновское значение, можно было бы его передать внутри списка единственным элементом `[img]`, но с тензорами это как-то по-другому делается.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну да, если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно 1 изображение или пачку упаковать c помощью `tf.data.Dataset`, если 1 изображение, то такого вида `(1,150,80,1)`. Но вот пока только не пойму как это сделать xD

Comment: в tf это делается с помощью expand_dim, в pytorch - unsquueze. Предполагаю, что ждётся тензор размером BxWxHxC (порядок WxH и C может отличаться), C - число каналов, W, H - ширина и высота. У вас заход WxHxC - пропустили батч. Соответственно, верхний слой думает, что W = B.